# How to use Twitter Boostrap modals without using all of Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I want to use the [modals from Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals), but I can't switch over to using all of Twitter Bootstrap right now. I assume I need to use the LESS files directly. Can someone provide an example of how to use the Twitter Bootstrap modals in isolation?

Comment: Have you checked answers about conflicting frameworks ? Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813969/css-framework-for-an-app-with-existing-stylesheet/11841957#11841957

Comment: @Sherbrow thanks! I didn't know you could namespace TB like that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the customise page to specify which bits you want?

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

1. Choose components: Toggle all components then check only Modals in JS Components.
2. Select jQuery plugins: Toggle all jQuery plugins then check only Modals.
3. Customise variables: Modify any of the defaults if need be (make a note of what you customise here).
4. Download.

You should just end up with the styles required for the modals and also the jQuery plugin.

Then you can follow the documentation to get your modal up and running.

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at that page. Easier than I thought! Thanks!