# jqGrid + twitter bootstrap (2.1.0): navbar changes style

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out how to fix this problem but I don't seem to be able to find a solution.

I am using jqGrid 4.4.1 (jQuery UI 1.8.23) and I've just started to use twitter bootstrap.
As you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/ZHRaD/) the navigation bar is messy.
The page selector element is much longer than it should be.
This is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/3Yqpc/) with jqGrid without twitter bootstrap.

Is there anyone out there who can try to help me to fix this?
Are there any other issues I should be aware of?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Alternative solution : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11841957/1478467

Comment: @Sherbow: It's interesting. Let's see if someone comes up with something easier. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FortAwesome/FortAwesome.htm) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13865495/315935). I think it's what you wanted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you should includes additional CSS styles like

```css
input.ui-pg-input {
    width: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: normal
}
select.ui-pg-selbox {
    width: auto;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    line-height: normal
}
```

​see http://jsfiddle.net/ZHRaD/14/

**UPDATED**: [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FortAwesome/FortAwesome.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13865495/315935) show how to use [Font Awesome icons](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/). It's probably what you wanted to have.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. your CSS does the job. Hope I won't find any trouble with some other features.