# Bootstrap css and jqgrid css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid

I use bootplus.css for my designing portion and jqgrid for data representation but `bootplus.css` file change textbox and checkbox of jqgrid which is inside on gird. How to prevent `bootplus.css` file to effect jqgrid?

Comment: It seems that your question is duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12285539/315935). See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12298889/315935) as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Load the jqgrid CSS last in your html. This way it overwrites conflicting styles from bootplus.

For example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="bootplus.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
    <link href="jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  </head>
  <body>
  </body
</html>
```

But I think perhaps your problem will persist, since I saw the comment of Oleg on your question, which [answers in a more specific to jqgrid way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12298889/315935).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I m trying to do this but it not worked. if any demo  you have please give as sample. Thanks