# Unsetting CSS attributes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently use Twitter's Bootstrap for some small projectsand. I  put all the CSS changes in a new `.css` file. But how can I unset CSS attributes from the original `bootstrap.css`?

Already tired setting it to `0`, but that won't work for all attributes.

`.example { color: 0; }` for example doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any reasons why would you reset a property. You probably won't like it's default or inherited value, so why not just set it to a value you want? You can use [**Reset CSS**](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Comment: Maybe you should apply Twitter Bootstrap only to specific elements ? This might give you some pointers : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11841957/1478467 (not the same context, but still valid)

Answer (score 3):

It's better you specify your own value, since setting it to default may be tricky:

[Initial value for `color` property depends on user agent](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#colors)

Comment: Correct; then you just 'set' it back to your initial value. There is no common default value for `color`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.example { color:inherit; }
```

Comment: This will take color from parent, which is not the same thing as reseting in to default value which may be different across browesrs

Comment: It also is going to be different across elements; the default value for an <a> tag won't be `inherit`, for example.

Comment: @JuicyScripter `inherit` is as close as you'll get to "unsetting" the color property, whether it's good or bad practice. The better thing to do is set your own value to override.

Comment: @Rick the problem is - inheriting it from parent may be completely undesired if applied on certain tags like `a`, `input`, `select`, etc...