# Using bootstrap and jqueryui on same page conflicts?

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I have jqueryui and twitter bootstrap loaded on the same page. However they both contain a tooltip feature, the whole site is based on bootstrap so I can not remove that from the page, but some pages I want to use the jqueryui tooltip.  However it defaults to bootstrap. Is there any way for me to choose which library to use the function with? Without removing the library from the page?

Comment: There is a lot of overlap between jQuery UI and bootstrap. Even if you could avoid conflicts, I would recommend using only one.

Comment: Ok thank you. Is there a way, if I just download jqueryui with the tooltip function, for me to rename it to something else? If I did a find/replace on tooltip and made it tooltip2, would that work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [css framework for an app with existing stylesheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813969/css-framework-for-an-app-with-existing-stylesheet)