# Concerns of using jQueryUI and bootstrap on same page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need some functionality provided by bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/, and other functionality provided by jQueryUI https://jqueryui.com/.

Need I specifically look out for any potential conflicts?

Are there any general steps I could take to mitigate them?

EDIT. If you feel they should not be used on the same page and had to pick one or the other, please leave a comment.

EDIT 2.  [Can I use Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery UI at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048214/can-i-use-twitter-bootstrap-and-jquery-ui-at-the-same-time) seems to "maybe" imply it could be.  Comments in [Using bootstrap and jqueryui on same page conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013252/using-bootstrap-and-jqueryui-on-same-page-conflicts) state not to.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of overlap between Bootstrap and jQuery Ui.  You can use them both together, but it requires care in your programming.  This is something that we are using at my employer, so I know it can be done.

You also need to keep in mind that Bootstrap and jQuery Ui are fundamentally different in their use.  Bootstrap operates under the declaritive model where you "decorate" your html with attributes and the Bootstrap JavaScript automatically hooks things up.  In jQuery Ui, you have to manually code in JavaScript to attach the jQuery Ui functions to controls.

One way to minimize the overlap would be to use the custom download builder at http://jqueryui.com/download/.  This way you would have a version of the jQuery Ui library has only the features that you absolutely want.

Comment: Currently, I have zero experience with bootstrap, and quite a lot with jQueryUI.  I previously have not used anything but the complete jQueryUI package as well.  Seems like I need to experiment more with bootstrap and if I like use it for all tasks except those I specifically wish to use UI.

Comment: As a suggestion, start by using Bootstrap functions that jQuery Ui doesn't have.  The responsive grid is great.  After that, add in functionality that jQuery Ui doesn't have.  Also checkout http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/, Great way to style checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about leveraging repositories that already exist? A quick search brings up [JQuery UI Bootstrap](https://jquery-ui-bootstrap.github.io/jquery-ui-bootstrap/)

[image]

It's also found on [Github](https://github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/jquery-ui-bootstrap), so you can fork it and modify to your hearts content.

Comment: Thanks Chase,  Yes I saw jQueryUI Bootstap, but haven't yet tried it.  Have you?  THanks

Comment: I have not because I don't use jQuery without Angular. So I use [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

Comment: I am planning on learning about Angular, but haven't yet done so.  I noticed that the referenced library (and others which I have found) don't support current bootstrap.  I would expect Angular to have more support.

Comment: Angular is good, but there are better kids on the block now. I'm finding it to be too slow to work with, Check out [Mithril](https://lhorie.github.io/mithril/), it's flippin' fast. - note: I have nothing to do with the project, just found it and like it.