# Using Twitter Bootstrap for just a subset of website

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Are there any caveats one should be aware of when building a subset / components of a website using Twitter Bootstrap or jQuery UI Bootstrap? Would there be any steps I'd need to take to make sure bootstrap doesn't effect parts of the website outside the scope of bootstrapped components?

Comment: Check that too http://stackoverflow.com/q/11813969/1478467

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap and Jquery ui bootstrap cant workout together  . There will be lot of  css and javscript conflicts . So to use them together you will have to use a customized copy of bootstrap by deselecting those components you want to use from jquery ui bootstrap .

Apart from that if you want to use some part of bootstrap with your existing project or an ongoin one . 
Head over to **Customize Bootstrap** section http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

And select things you need  and download the copy to use.  Also while naming your custom styles use different names than already defined in bootstrap .

Comment: Thats the jquery ui I am talking about . bootstrap and jquery ui have conflicts in styles and js .. so suppose you want to use tooltip from jquery ui than you shouldnt include the default tooltip from bootstrap . Anything more specific you want to know ?

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS closures.

Limit twitter bootstrap for the part by limiting the view of the required css

Eg:

```
#divPart .btn {

}

#divPart .btn-large {

}

#divPart .table {

}
```

I hope you understood.

Comment: You can even wrap the entire boostrap less file in a closure, like .bootstrap {}, the you'll just add .bootstrap to the parent and bootstrap will be used on all childs :)