# Compiling issue in Bootstrap 3 with namespace

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

Any idea why there are certain styles breaking when I compile Bootstrap 3 using Crunch / WinLESS.  I'm using this code to namespace bootstrap.

```
.namespace-bs {
    @import "less/bootstrap.less";
}
```

For most styles it works great but there are a few that turn out like this:

```
.btn-primary .namespace-bs .caret,.btn-success .namespace-bs .caret,.btn-warning .namespace-bs .caret,.btn-danger .namespace-bs .caret,.btn-info .namespace-bs .caret{border-top-color:#fff;}
```

When I would expect them to be like this:

```
.namespace-bs .btn-primary .caret,.namespace-bs .btn-success .caret,.namespace-bs .btn-warning .caret,.namespace-bs .btn-danger .caret,.namespace-bs .btn-info .caret{border-top-color:#fff;}
```

Is there something wrong with my compiler or a bug in the LESS code?

Thanks

Comment: it could be great you mention Where TF you are editing that first line, that could help other people, instead of only helping you

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you are asking but if you mean where the .namespace-bs { @import "less/bootstrap.less"; } is located, then I made a new .less file with only that line of code in it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Your Issue in Detail

As seven-phases-max described, there are issues with name spacing "when the `&` is *appended* to a nested selector." So the Bootstrap code in part has this:

```
.caret {
  .btn-default & {
    border-top-color: @btn-default-color;
  }
  .btn-primary &,
  .btn-success &,
  .btn-warning &,
  .btn-danger &,
  .btn-info & {
    border-top-color: #fff;
  }
}
```

Recall that every instance of `&` is replaced with the *full nesting structure*, so when you namespace it as you are, you effectively have this:

```
.namespace-bs {
  .caret {
    .btn-default & {
      border-top-color: @btn-default-color;
    }
    .btn-primary &,
    .btn-success &,
    .btn-warning &,
    .btn-danger &,
    .btn-info & {
      border-top-color: #fff;
    }
  }
}
```

And the full nested structure is `.namespace .caret` at the point of the `&` replacement, which is why you are seeing the selectors look like `.btn-primary .namespace-bs .caret` etc.

### Work Around for LESS 1.4+

The following should work:

1. Compile bootstrap from its LESS code as normal into a `bootstrap.css` file. This will resolve all LESS into the "normal" bootstrap css code, and the `&` will function as expected and desired wherever it is used.
2. Then in your name spacing LESS file, do this:

```css
.namespace-bs {
    @import (less) "css/bootstrap.css";
}
```

What we are doing is importing the compiled `bootstrap.css` file (which has no more `&` values in it, as it is fully compiled), but as we import it, [we are telling LESS to treat the CSS as LESS code by putting the `(less)` type casting in](http://lesscss.org/#-importing). So now, your name space should simply append itself to the full selector string of each selector in the `bootstrap.css` file, and you should end up with what you desire.

Comment: However this problem seems to have been fixed in version 3.2

Comment: @Svakinn No, it's not fixed. v3.2 may fix the particular `.btn` case but there a lot of other classes and styles that gets broken if you wrap "bootstrap.less" into a namespace. In fact, it just *cannot* be fixed with current state of Less and Bootstrap w/o some (quite major) refactoring of both. See [#2052](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2052#issuecomment-45681469) and other issues referenced from there.

Comment: @Svakinn In other words, the `@import (less) "css/bootstrap.css";` solution is the only solution for the moment (and will be the only solution for a while).

Comment: Yes @seven-phases-max you are absolutley right. To believe 3.2 fixed the problem was due to silly mistake on my behalf. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: FYI - When doing step 1 my compiler doesn't work with step 2 unless the CSS from step 1 isn't minified.

Comment: @Overachiever same issue here. My less compiler is set up to only compile the .min.css and not the unminified css file, so I don't have an unminified bootstrap file to reference. Why doesn't minified css work? It is valid css and less afterall.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's nothing wrong with either compiler or your code. It's just "Bootstrap is not meant to be used this way". Putting a whole less file into namespace is a wise idea but it is incompatible with libraries having selectors using so-called ["Parent-Selectors"](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature) or similar tricks (i.e. when `&` is *appended* to a nested selector).

(*Updated*) See [#2052](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2052#issuecomment-45681469) and other issues referenced from there for more details.