# How to properly namespace bootstrap 3 to work with other bootstrap 3 instances which are not namespaced

Tags: php, css, regex, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

We work in the wordpress environment and [namespacing bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793508/compiling-issue-in-bootstrap-3-with-namespace) simply is not enough as many other things might conflict and not every developer is namespacing this. 
SO the only option i see is to namespace the classes so that instead of `.row` i have to use in my markup `.namespace-row`.

Any ideas on how to make that efficiently and know if someone has already tackled this?I guess a regexp is the way to go, or a php script.

EDIT - Since i've been voted down, i'll try to be more clear. Bootstrap classes are very general like `row`. Namespacing has been suggested as a solution but in the wordpress environment this is not enough as a template might use a row class. so even if we namespace conflicts arise. My idea was to namespace classes so that in bootstrap code `.row` becomes `.namespace-row`. I guess i could use a regexp to accomodate this, i just wanted to know if someone has already done this and share his/her experience.

EDIT 2 - Ok let's try to be even more precise. The route i'm going down is parsing with [Lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/). 
so i have my bootstrap code in $css_to_parse

```
$parsed_css = $this->lessc->parse( $css_to_parse, $variables );
```

i now see two possibilities: a regular expression or hacking Lessphp for namespacing when parsing.
I tried using `'s|([\.#])([a-z][^\s,]+)|$1ai1ec-$2|i'` as a regex but it's not working 100% as sometimes not everything is namespaced, for example i get

```
.ai1ec-open .dropdown-toggle.btn-success
```

where i would expect

```
 .ai1ec-open .ai1ec-dropdown-toggle.ai1ec-btn-success
```

so the regexp might need some tuning.

Comment: try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813969/css-framework-for-an-app-with-existing-stylesheet/11841957#11841957

Comment: @MrFishes i said that simply namespacing is not enough, we already do that.

Comment: Complicated, and messy.  If I wanted to do this I would fork Lesscss so instead of nesting classes it prefixed them.  It should still be compatible with existing less libraries, but their usage would difer.

Comment: @Flosculus actually i'm using Lessphp to compile bootstrap i might see if it can be done there

Comment: Yeah you can use LESS to prefix your css, I've done this in the past and works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

I created a custom namespaced stylesheet of version 3.1.1 at [sassmeister.com](http://sassmeister.com):

https://gist.github.com/awesome/9676554#file-sassmeister-output-css

Include it after existing bootstrap versions, then wrap any element you want to be v3.1.1 with the class `twbs-3_1_1`.

Example:

```
<div class="twbs-3_1_1 panel panel-default"></div>
```