# Bootstrap 3 LESS, apply styling only to a certain container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I want to include bootsrtap3 only into a certain container. What I did, I downloaded bootstrap sources, went to `\bootstrap-3.1.0\less` renamed `bootstrap.less` to `bootstrap2.less`, created `bootsrap.less`, added to it

```
.tw-bs {
    @import "bootstrap2.less";
}
```

Which I found in some answer on stackoverflow I don't remember now. And which should've enclosed every rule in `.tw-bs`.

It worked for most rules, actually for all of them. But, when I looked closely at resulting `.css` files, I found some strange rules, like:

`td.tw-bs .visible-print`

or

`.tw-bs .tw-bs .modal-footer:after`

or

`a.tw-bs .bg-primary:hover`

That doesn't make sence, as `.tw-bs` should always be a parent. What I did wrong, and why this nonsence rules were generated?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793508, [#1709](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1709).

Answer (score 3):

Its a namespacing issue when using the & selector. Compile the bootstrap and import it.

Comment: can you please elaborate, how to do it? At first I'm compiling bootsrap, then I have bootsrap.css. What's then? I'm a bit new with less and was compiling bootsrap by following instructions on their website. So I'm not sure what should I do after creating new less file containing `.namespace-bs {
    @import (less) "css/bootstrap.css";
}` what should I do with my new `mybootrap.less` next? Compile it with less? How? From where?

Comment: Compile the new file using WinLess or whatever method you generally use. You can keep bootstrap.css in the folder as it is unless you plan to change it. In your case change namespace to .tw-bs since the Bootstrap is already compiled you wont get those weird styles.