# What is the best way to use Bootstrap and 960gs simultaneously?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, 960.gs

I have a website project that I'm doing in Bootstrap3, but the top menu was done in 960gs. What is the best way to use both at the same time, without one interfering with the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to not use both.  960gs is not responsive.  Instead of spending the time to make it responsive, it would be more advisable to create the menu using bootstrap so it's responsive from the start and you eliminate a secondary framework.

If you want to move forward with using both frameworks you can namespace bootstrap.  This has already been answered here:

[How to namespace Twitter Bootstrap so styles don't conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966259/how-to-namespace-twitter-bootstrap-so-styles-dont-conflict)

and

[css framework for an app with existing stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813969/css-framework-for-an-app-with-existing-stylesheet/11841957#11841957)

Comment: Thank you! I'll do the menu in bootstrap then;